# JSON React arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs

I am kind of stuck I have  JSON file which has arrays, so  I want to when I click on the div to open  only one "array" instead of that it opens them all, basically I want to switch between them. I would be very grateful if you could help me .Thanks in Advance . Edit
I have more arrays in json file now it double renders them

```
[
{

"id":0,
 "name": "Aatrox",
"image": "/champions/Aatrox_0.jpg",

"textQ":"Q",
"qInfo": "The darlking Blade Aatrox slams his greatsword down, dealing physical damage. He can swing three times, each with a different area of effect",
"image1": "/spell/AatroxQ.png",          
"textW": "W",
 "wInfo": "Aatrox smashes the ground, dealing damage to the first enemy hit. Champions and large monsters have to leave the impact area quickly or they will be dragged to the center and take the damage again.",
 "image2" : "/spell/AatroxW.png",
 "textE" : "E",
 "eInfo" : " Passively, Aatrox heals when damaging enemy champions. On activation, he dashes in a direction.",
 "image3" :"/spell/AatroxE.png",
 "textR" : "R",
 "RInfo" : "Aatrox unleashes his demonic form, fearing nearby enemy minions and gaining attack damage, increased healing, and movement speed. If he gets a takedown, this effect is extended."    , 
 "image4" : "/spell/AatroxR.png"
}

]
```

```
import React  from 'react'
import data from './data.json'
import  './Champions.css'

function Champions() {
  const[toggleShow, setToggleShow]= React.useState(false) 
      
    return (
       <div className='champions'>
       {data.map((postData)=>{
        console.log(postData);
         return(      
           <div onClick={()=> setToggleShow((toggleShow) =>!toggleShow)}key= 
           {postData.id}>
          <div className='champion'>       
         <img className='champion__Image'src={postData.image}></img>                   
          <h4 className="champion__Name">{postData.name}</h4>  
          
           {!toggleShow && 
            <Skills/>}
          </div>
         
          </div>
       )

Skills Component
import React from 'react';
import "./Skills.css";
import data from './data.json'

function Skills () {
             
    return (       
            <div className="spells">
        {data.map((postData)=>{
            console.log(postData)       
            return(
                <div>                 
                   <img alt="123"className='image__Q'src={postData.image1}></img>
                    <p>{postData.textQ}</p>
                    <h4>{postData.qInfo}</h4>
                   <img alt="123"className='image__Q'src={postData.image2}></img>
                    <p>{postData.textW}</p>
                    <h4>{postData.wInfo}</h4>
                    <p>{postData.textE}</p>
                    <h4>{postData.eInfo}</h4>
                    <p>{postData.textR}</p>
                    <h4>{postData.RInfo}</h4>
                   
                    </div>     
  )
  
   })}
   </div>
        
    )
}

export default Skills
```

Comment: Place each one into another component, and then each one will have it's own state.  The trick with React, don't create huge single components, but compose them from lots of smaller ones.  Do this, and it all becomes a lot easier.

Comment: Did that the First time

Comment: @Keith Did not work

Comment: That's how you do it, show us your first attempt were you did this, and then we might be able to see were you went wrong.

Comment: @Keith Here you go

Comment: You showed only one object in the array, so you're meaning normally there is more  object for each champions or only one object ?

Comment: I have 100 more

Comment: Your state for toggleShow needs putting inside your skills component.

Comment: @Keith you sure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood good, you will have many object in the JSON, and you want to only get one object?

If so, this will work

```
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import data from "./data.json";

const Champions = () => {
  const [toggleShow, setToggleShow] = useState(false);
  const [currentSelectedChampion, setCurrentSelectedChampion] = useState({});

  const handleSelectChampion = (id) => {
    if (!toggleShow) setToggleShow(true);
    const currentChampion = data.filter((champ) => champ.id === id)[0];
    setCurrentSelectedChampion(currentChampion);
  };

  return (
    <div className="champions">
      {data.map((postData) => {
        return (
          <div onClick={() => handleSelectChampion(postData.id)}>
            <div className="champion">
              <img className="champion__Image" src={postData.image}></img>
              <h4 className="champion__Name">{postData.name}</h4>
              {toggleShow && currentSelectedChampion.id === postData.id && (
                <>
                  <Skills currentChampion={currentSelectedChampion} />
                  <p onClick={() => setToggleShow(false)}>Close</p>
                </>
              )}
            </div>
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
};

const Skills = ({ currentChampion }) => {
  return (
    <div className="spells">
      <div>
        <h1>{currentChampion.name}</h1>
        <p> {currentChampion.textQ}</p>
        <h4>{currentChampion.qInfo}</h4>
        <p> {currentChampion.textW}</p>
        <h4>{currentChampion.wInfo}</h4>
        <p> {currentChampion.textE}</p>
        <h4>{currentChampion.eInfo}</h4>
        <p> {currentChampion.textR}</p>
        <h4>{currentChampion.RInfo}</h4>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<Champions />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

However, I recommend you to refactor your architecture and wrapp skills and champions in a main component, and passe directly the current champion to each of them. So you will have to filter your data only once.
The codesandbox link is here: https://codesandbox.io/s/heuristic-blackwell-sqybi?file=/src/App.js:0-960

Image result :[image]

Comment: I want when I click on the specific champ that it displays info only about that one

Comment: Yes. but the json file you've puted on the top only show one object in the array. You're meaning there is multiple objects normally on the array and you want to get the single object corresponding to the the champ ? If so, my answer is the way to go, you just need to filter by name, or id, or whatever you get the value from

Comment: They are multiple objects in the array, I want to when i click on the specific image that opens up info for that champ

Comment: I've updated the code, and its works perfectly, i've added some refactor aswell, please let me know if you have errors or validate the answer if it fits for you, the full code is on the codesanbox by the way

Comment: this is before https://imgur.com/W76AIOM this is what happens when I click on img https://imgur.com/xTSdrwS

Comment: Anyway my guy ill figure it out you gave a I would call this a hint . I was just wondering what Dev Lvl are you Senior or Mid

Comment: Im still a student. But i dont understand, did you check the codesandbox link i've provided ? beceause for me it only show the current champion data... Look my answer i've added a screenshot

Comment: I have done it or you have. The only slight  problem is when I click on img it moves the content to the top https://imgur.com/rv48bvA

Comment: Yes this you need to handle your css to display it correctly, but the important is, as you asked, to get only a single object value when clicked. if it. Good luck to it .) and DEMACIAAAAAAAA

Comment: @ Thank you my g. But for some reason I dont believe that you are a Student

Comment: May I ask you something